# Paralelismo en procesos en C

Tags: c

Hola buenas tengo una duda y es que tengo un programa que me crea n procesos y cada proceso cree un proceso. El proceso padre lo que hara sera esperar a todos los hijos y los espera. El problema es que primero espera a los ultimos hijos creados en vez de al primero. Les dejo aquí una captura de pantalla donde se muestra lo que comento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, debería esperar primero al proceso 19382, luego 19383 y luego 19384. Sin embargo lo hace al revés siempre y me gustaría saber si se puede esperar en orden de llegada. Os dejo aquí el código del programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(int argc,char **argv){
    if(argc!=2){
        printf("Error en la entrada de datos\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int status,n=atoi(argv[1]);
    pid_t pid,pidd;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        pid=fork();
        if(pid==0){ //Caso hijo
            printf("Soy el hijo %i y mi PID es %i y el de mi padre es %i\n",i+1,getpid(),getppid());
        }
        else if(pid>0){ //Caso padre
            pidd=wait(&status);
            if(WIFEXITED(status)){
                printf("Proceso hijo %i esperado por padre con status %i \n",pidd,WEXITSTATUS(status));
            }
            else if(WIFSIGNALED(status)){
                printf("Hijo %i ha muerto por señal con estado %i\n",pidd,WTERMSIG(status));
            }
            else if(WIFSTOPPED(status)){
                printf("Hijo %i ha muerto por un error con estado %i\n",pidd,WSTOPSIG(status));
            }
            else{
                printf("Error en la espera al hijo %i\n",errno);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else{ //Error
            printf("Error en el fork %i\n",errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que tener en cuenta que la ejecución de los hijos es totalmente aleatoria: es **el sistema** el que decide cuando se ejecutan y durante cuanto tiempo, por lo que, en principio, el orden de su *muerte* es impredecible. Dicho esto ...

> Me gustaría saber si se pueden esperar en orden

Es perfectamente posible, pero hay que cambiar algunas cosas en tu código:

1. Dividir en 2 tareas: crear los hijos y esperar a los hijos.
2. Necesitamos guardar en algún sitio los `pid` de los hijos cuando se crean.
3. Tenemos que llamar a [`waitpid( )`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid), que permite indicar a que hijo queremos esperar.

Aplicando esos cambios, nos queda:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    if( argc != 2 ) {
        printf( "Error en la entrada de datos\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
 
    int n = atoi( argv[1] );
    pid_t *pids = malloc( sizeof( pid_t ) * n );

    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        pids[i] = fork( );

        if( pids[i] == 0 ){
            printf( "Soy el hijo %i y mi PID es %i y el de mi padre es %i\n", i + 1, getpid( ), getppid( ) );
            exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        } else if( pids[i] < 0 ) {
            printf( "Error en el fork %i\n", errno );
        }
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        if( pids[i] < 0 ) { continue; }

        int status;
        pid_t pidd = waitpid( pids[i], &status, 0 );

        if( WIFEXITED( status ) ) {
            printf( "Proceso hijo %i esperado por padre con status %i \n", pidd, WEXITSTATUS( status ) );
        } else if( WIFSIGNALED( status ) ) {
            printf( "Hijo %i ha muerto por señal con estado %i\n", pidd, WTERMSIG( status ) );
        } else if( WIFSTOPPED(status)){
            printf( "Hijo %i ha muerto por un error con estado %i\n", pidd, WSTOPSIG( status ) );
        } else{
            printf( "Error en la espera al hijo %i\n", errno );
        }
    }

    free( pids );

    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Como ves, hacemos exactamente lo que indicaba al principio:

- 2 bucles `for( )`: primero creamos y luego esperamos. Además, así nos aseguramos de no ir dejando hijos huérfanos por ahí, que puede tener penas de cárcel :-)
- Una lista con los `pid` de los hijos. Al usar 2 bucles, necesitamos un sitio en el que guardar nuestras cositas.
- Llamamos a `waitpid( )` indicando a que hijo queremos esperar.

Y el resultado es:

> ./test 3
> Soy el hijo 1 y mi PID es 3076 y el de mi padre es 3075
> Soy el hijo 2 y mi PID es 3077 y el de mi padre es 3075
> Soy el hijo 3 y mi PID es 3078 y el de mi padre es 3075
> Proceso hijo 3076 esperado por padre con status 0
> Proceso hijo 3077 esperado por padre con status 0
> Proceso hijo 3078 esperado por padre con status 0